# Avoiding ifs using patterns

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I know that you can remove if blocks by using polymorphism with Strategy or Command patterns. However, let's say my code looks something like this:

```
ArgumentObject arg = getArg();

if (arg.getId() == "id2_1" || arg.getId() == "id3_1" || arg.getId() == "id4_1") {
    //do something
}
if (arg.getId() == "id2_1") {
    //do something
}
if (arg.getId() = "id2_2" || arg.getId() = "id3_1") {
    //do something
}
if (arg.getId().startsWith("id1") || arg.getId().startsWith("id4")) {
    //do something
}
```

Basically, the code performs some fields population actions based on product's id. It checks whether product comes from some group of products with startsWith(), then performs population, checks if a product has a particular id, then populates fields appropriately, etc.

I am not sure how can I use Strategy pattern here? If I create one Strategy to handle first if statement, then how can I proceed handling the second statement? The problem is that the ifs aren't mutually exclusive. Should I just move the relevant ifs to Strategy classes? Any pattern that would help me refactor this so its easier to test?

Comment: I really don't see any reason why you'd even attempt to use the strategy pattern in this case. Perhaps if you explain your business problem in a more realistic fashion, you can get a more realistic solution.

Comment: Also you should compare strings using `equals()` method not with `==`.

Comment: Your code can be reduced: The second and the third `if` are redundant when also copying their code into the first `if`.

Comment: Well, there are like 100 if statements in the class, and I have to write unit test for it. I thought extracting some code into strategies would make the test much smaller and easier to write, and just test the strategies with logic in other tests..

Comment: Yes, they are redundant, because its just an example. In the application every if is neccessary..

Comment: @eek are any of these answers useful to you? If so, upvote and accept. If not, maybe some comments to explain why not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem your code reveals is somewhat more basic: It violates the *Tell! Don't ask!* principle.

Instead of having a method `getId()`your `arg`objects should have a common interface method which is called at this point. The work to be done could be injected to the `arg` objects when they are instantiated, or they could be passed as Parameters to the method and the concrete Inmplementation of the `arg` object decides which parameter to call...

Comment: Hmm, argument object in our architecture is just a plain transfer object containing no business logic and is always the same. It is generated by filling UI form. Then, based on this object, new data transfer objects are created that contains data for different database calls. Then the response objects from database get combined into final response object that is used further. I can't put any logic in arg object:( Your suggestion still seems similar to Strategy pattern, as for different objects I would have different behavior, same as with different strategies that operate on object.

Comment: @eek *"argument object in our architecture is just a plain transfer object containing no business logic"* in that case you should pass it through a Factory creating wrapper objects with the logic needed to handle each ID...

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks the business logic for these ifs. 
But I can make some assumptions from :

> Basically, the code performs some fields population actions based on product's id. It checks whether product comes from some group of products with startsWith(), then performs population, checks if a product has a particular id, then populates fields appropriately, etc.

I am assuming all you if blocks are specific business logic and are independent of each other.
You can try Decorator Pattern for this. As the wiki says:

*Decorator Pattern is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class*

Your case can be viewed as :

```
public Product{

    private String id;
    //other fields
}


   ProductDecoratorInterface{

       Product populateItem(Product product);

    }

ProductXYZDecorator{

   @Override
   public Product populateItem(Product product){
   // check the id for 1,2,3
   //do the field population

}

}

    ProductABCDecorator{

    @Override
    public Product populateItem(Product product){
    // check the id for 1,3
    //do the field population

    }

    }
```

Your main class would look like:

```
public Mainclass{

List<ProductDecoratorInterface> decorators;


public void someFn(Product product){
   decorators.stream.forEach(i -> i.populateItem(product));
}

}
```

}

...

> Any pattern that would help me refactor this so its easier to test?

Here you would need to test just the individual Decorators.

You would need to maintain the list of all decorator and pass your object through all of them.
This is not the proper use of the pattern but helps solve your use case(testing complexity).

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to get rid of your `if` based code entirely, but you may be able to tidy it up into a more appropriate class.

The `if`s are *domain logic*, and if it makes sense within the domain then you could write an object solely responsible for this classification:

```
 interface ArgumentClassifier {
      Classification classify(Argument arg);
 }
```

`Classification` would be an `enum`.

The implementation of this will contain your `if`s, encapsulating that domain logic.

- You can unit-test your `ArgumentClassifier` in isolation.
- If your `ArgumentClassifier` turns out to be large and complicated, you might well be able to break it up using the *Composite Pattern*.
- If you later find a different way to do the classification (e.g. a rules engine, a database lookup, etc.) you can write new implementations of `ArgumentClassifier`.

Now you can use the Strategy pattern:

```
  Map<Classification, Handler> strategies = ...;
  ArgumentClassifier classifier = new SimpleArgumentClassifier();

  private Foo handleArg(Argument arg) {
      return strategies
          .get(classifier.classify(arg))
          .handle(arg);  
  }
```

Whether all this is worthwhile or not, depends on your specific needs.

If:

- The class you're working in is already the natural home of that domain logic
- The class you're working on has good cohesion

... then it may be wiser to leave the `if` logic where it is.

---

Another approach to classification is to build a binary number or a string from predicates about the object being classified. For example:

```
 int classification(Person p) {
     return 0
         | ( p.getGender() == Gender.MALE ? 1 : 0 )
         | ( p.isEmployed()               ? 2 : 0 )
         | ( p.age >= 18                  ? 4 : 0 );
 }
```

This gives you a classification of `0b001` for an unemployed 17-year-old male, `0b010` for an employed 17-year-old female, and so on.

You can use these directly as keys to a map of strategies (it could be many-to-one). Or you can do further bitwise manipulation to reduce them to a smaller set.

There's a lot of scope here, but take care not to lose sight of simplicity and clarity. Sometimes a chain of `if/else` gets the job done, is clear and effective.

Comment: Note I've removed the word "Object" from the name of `ArgumentObject`. All objects are objects, so having the word "Object" in a class name is tautological clutter.